# How to configure Apache to present a specified localhost site to the internet

Tags: apache, web-services, configuration, dns

I'm a Web developer and I have a domain. Let's just say it's `example.com`. I want to create a sub domain `website1.example.com` that links to my home office computer. That's easy. The sub domain points to the ip address of my router that forwards port 80 to my home office computer.

The challenge I'm having is configuring Apache to present `website1.localhost` because currently it's only presenting the default Website `localhost`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add a `ServerAlias website1.example.com` directive to your VirtualHost section in httpd.conf.
This way you let Apache know it needs to serve your website under different name as well.

Comment: That works fine. I just had to change `<VirtualHost 127.0.0.1>` to account for my ip.